# using JQuery to fill the checked items into hidden field

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I want to fill my checked items (from checkbox) into a hidden field in a comma separated form, here is my data:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChargerTypesIDs)
        <div class="container">
           <form role="form">
               <div class="checkbox">

                   @foreach (ChargingSpots_Web_Application.Models.ChargerType ct in ViewBag.ChargerTypes)
                   {

                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="@ct.ChargerTypeID" /> @ct.Description <br></label>   

                   }
               </div>
           </form>
           </div>
```

Comment: Yes (you need jaascript/jquery). What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried any because I am not familiar with JQuery

Comment: Time to start learning :) (but why would you want to do this any way - as opposed to having a `int[] ChargerTypesIDs` property in you model and giving the checkboxes `name="ChargerTypesIDs"`?

Comment: you mean like this: <label><input type="checkbox" value="@ct.ChargerTypeID" name="ChargerTypesIDs" />

Comment: Exactly (and change `ChargerTypesIDs` to a collection property and delete the hidden input)

Comment: public  Collection<ChargerType> ChargerTypesIDs { get; set; }
is this enough ??

Comment: No it needs to be a value type. If `ChargerTypeID` is typeof `int` then it needs to be `int[] ChargerTypesIDs` (or `IEnumerable<int> ChargerTypesIDs`)`

Comment: they are of type String so is this fine:
public  IEnumerable<String> ChargerTypesIDs { get; set; }
?

Comment: That will work fine - in the post method, the collection will contain the all the selected ID's

Comment: public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ChargingSpotID,ArabicName,EnglishName,Description,LocationLat,LocationLong,IsPrivate")] ChargingSpot chargingspot,ChargerType chargerType)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ChargingSpots.Add(chargingspot);
                db.ChargerTypes.Add(chargerType);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(chargingspot);
        }
is this fine ?

Comment: Impossible to read in comments. If your having problems edit your question with the code you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: ok thank you very much